# change child framelayout height,width,gravity programmatically?

Tags: html, android-framelayout

**change child framelayout height,width,gravity programmatically?**

> I have linearlayout as parent and framelayout as child now I want to change height and width of framelayout programmatically

**code I tried but does not effect at all**

```
public void frame_params(FrameLayout bottomFrameLayout, int weight, int height) {
    bottomFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(weight, height);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;
    bottomFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

}
```

**xml**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/hv_effect"
        android:layout_below="@+id/effect_hedaer_toolbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left">
</FrameLayout>
</Linearlayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line is your problem:

```
bottomFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(context);
```

In the `frame_params` method, you receive a `FrameLayout`. But, then, you instantiate a NEW one with that line. So, indeed, the FrameLayout inside the LinearLayout will continue the same way, because you are not changing it, you are creating a new FrameLayout and you're setting the parameters to it. Just try removing the aforementioned line, like this:

```
public void frame_params(FrameLayout bottomFrameLayout, int weight, int height) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(weight, height);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;
    bottomFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

}
```

And, then, pass the correct FrameLayout (the one with the id "FrameLayout", as specified in your xml), it should work.

Let me know if it worked, and, if it did, remember to upvote/select as the correct answer, cheers : )